# API for real time analysis of Twitter feed?

Tags: web-services, api, twitter, real-time, twitter-feed

I wanted to know if there are any existing API's used to evaluate any pattern or something out of the real-time twitter feeds?

I'm looking for any API's/Web Services that could work with .NET

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://datasift.net/ does that to some extent (but you'll need to apply to be an alpha tester).

I've used it and it's pretty good.